# value of key A equals to value of Key B in JSONschema

Tags: schema, jsonschema

For `{keyA:valueA},{KeyB:valueB}` Is it possible to define in the schema, `valueB` must equal to `valueA`. In other words, copying down `ValueA` to `ValueB`?

I understand it causes duplication. But two different keys must be used to meet different standards.

For example, I want to use `name` as `sample name` in the schema below.

Schema

```
{
    "$id": "sampleSchema",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "sample name":{
            "type":"string"
        },
    }
}
```

The data will be like:

```
{
 "name":"example1",
 "sample name":"example1"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON Schema does not support operations like this.

We call this "data consistency validation" because it tests that data in one place is *consistent* with how it's defined in another location.

Supporting these types of operations would be very difficult. It would probably require a general purpose programming language to support most of the cases that people would like to see.

For more information, see [Scope of JSON Schema Validation](https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/wiki/Scope-of-JSON-Schema-Validation).

As an alternative, some validators allow you to implement custom keywords, or implement events or hooks when an instance is being validated against a schema with a particular ID. You can use this to implement the functionality you're looking for.